# Barplot in seaborn with height based on an array

Tags: python, bar-chart, seaborn

Set `y=[0.7,0.2,0.1,0.05]` and `x=[1,2,3,4]`, how do I create a barplot/barchart in seaborn where the height is specified by `y` for the label given in `x` i.e the first bar has height 0.7, the second bar has height 0.2 etc just like in `matplotlib`

`plt.bar(x=[1,2,3,4],height=y)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can pass it directly as x and y, without a data.frame:

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.set()
sns.barplot(x=[1,2,3,4],y=[0.7,0.2,0.1,0.05])
```

[image]

If you don't want different colors for the bar, do:

```
sns.barplot(x=[1,2,3,4],y=[0.7,0.2,0.1,0.05],color="b")
```

Comment: I actually tried that, but it threw me an error regarding that I could not use "x" and "y" at the same time, but now it works!